# How to fix CommandAcceptanceException in hsqldb integration test?

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I use `hsqldb 2.4.0` library for test my DAO layer (Hibernate 5.2.10). I create separate `hibernate.cfg.xml` for `hsqldb` in dir `test/resources/hibernate.cfg.xml`. But when I run test then get `CommandAcceptanceException`:

```
2017-08-04T20:34:35.755+0300  WARN  GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlString(SchemaDropperImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaDropperImpl.java:359)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.applyConstraintDropping(SchemaDropperImpl.java:331)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.dropFromMetadata(SchemaDropperImpl.java:230)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.performDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:154)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaDropperImpl.doDrop(SchemaDropperImpl.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:144)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:309)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:452)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:710)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at ru.pravvich.dao.DAOImplTest.before(DAOImplTest.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
Hibernate: drop table propose if exists

    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
Hibernate: drop table users if exists
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.PROPOSE
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: user lacks privilege or object not found: PUBLIC.PROPOSE
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.SchemaManager.getUserTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlterTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDDL.compileAlter(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatements(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeDirectStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

It's not a compatible version of syntax (If I understand correctly). But in `hibernate.cfg.xml` the version defined `HSQLDialect`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="http://www.hibernate.org/xsd/orm/cfg">
    <session-factory>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:auto_mag;sql.enforce_size=false</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>

        <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/User.hbm.xml" />
        <mapping resource="ru/pravvich/model/Propose.hbm.xml" />
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Help me to find the mistake. Thank You.

Comment: The stack shows it drops the `propose` table first, then executes `alter table propose ...`, which fails because the table no longer exists.

Comment: @fredt yes now I see thank You. But creating is automatically. How to fix this. In root of project create mem.log, mem.properties, mem.script files and when I delete them I get this issue.